# "Day before yesterday" - How to say for Week, Month, and Year

Tags: phrase-request

I went to beach **day before yesterday**.

Likewise, how to say for **Week, Month, and Year**?

> ... week before last week
>   ... month before last month
>   ... year before last year

Actually, I should not specify any month (July) or year (2015).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> I went to the beach **the** day before yesterday
>
> Week, Month and Year

I saw John the week before last.

I went to a rock concert the month before last.

I was in the USA the year before last.

**Notes**

1. I speak British English and we always use '**the** X before last'
2. It may be the case that some varieties of English omit 'the'.  I don't know.
3. It is less usual with month and year but people will still know what it means.
4. You can also say things like 'the term before last', 'the semester before last' etc.

Comment: Occasionally in very informal AmE we may omit the article, but usually that's not the case.

Answer (score 3):

You can say "the week before last" or "the year before last" (and possibly likewise with "month", though, for some reason, it doesn't sound quite as idiomatic to me), but for all three you can simply say "two weeks/months/years ago" with expresses the idea simply and efficiently in the fewest words possible.